# How do I read an EDN file from ClojureScript running on NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, clojurescript

I have a simple data file in EDN format I need to read in a ClojureScript cli app running on NodeJS, but none of the relevant core libraries from Clojure seem to be available (core.java.io/read, clojure.edn/read, etc.)

What should I be using instead?

Comment: AFAIK, it should be possible: https://github.com/logseq/logseq/blob/7c85920d9202b0bb5f244b2ab796c62b102518e9/src/main/frontend/extensions/zotero.cljs#L3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or even easier use `readFileSync` (`shadow-cljs` example):

```
  (require '["fs" :as fs]
           '[cljs.reader :as reader])

  (defn read-edn [path]
    (-> (.readFileSync fs path "utf8")
        reader/read-string))

  (read-edn "/xxx/yyy/zzz/my-data.edn")
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
(ns app.core
  (:require [cljs.reader :as reader]))

(def fs (js/require "fs"))

(defn read-edn [path f]
  (.readFile fs path "utf8" (fn [err data] (f (reader/read-string data)))))

(defn process [coll])

(read-edn "/tmp/x.clj" process)
```

In the example above, `process` would receive the data structure that was read from the file. You would need to implement `process` and add error handling to `read-edn`.